# Host the Sharepoint portal for Internet access provided windows authentication exist

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, hosting, web-hosting, sharepoint-2013

I have a requirement, that the SharePoint portal of our company should be made accessible from internet, as in
once URL is entered in the browser, it should ask for credentials- once entered, should display the homepage of the portal.
Provided it should be accessible from the current intranet also.
It is in windows authentication mode currently.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: This question would be more appropriate in a forum like SuperUser or Sharepoint StackExchange. I am not a system administrator so my answer will lack detail and probably wont be optimal.

The only thing you need to provide is access from an external interface to your network. So something that routes requests from outside of your network to your sharepoint instance.

This is usually achieved through a reverse proxy and proper configuration of DNS. You can setup a reverse proxy by different means, if your organisation uses the Microsoft Stack then I suggest setting up IIS as a reverse proxy to your Sharepoint Instance. There are multiple tutorials on how to do this on the web.

http://sahelp.sharepointforall.com/FAQ/bconfigure_IIS.html

You then need to add an entry to your organisation DNS hosting something like sharepoint.organisation.com that points to your external interface (public IP) where the reverse proxy is sitting.

You will then need to add an Alternate Access Mapping to your Sharepoint WebApplication so Sharepoint can route the requests that the proxy sends to the appropriate Webapplication.

http://blog.blksthl.com/2012/12/03/a-guide-to-alternate-access-mappings-basics-in-sharepoint-2013/

If you are using basic authentication make sure you enable SSL. this can be done in several ways but a possible and easy (but not the most secure) is to enable SSL just externally and then use a normal unencrypted channel on the inside of your network, this is probably the easiest setup but again not very secure as people inside the newtork can snoop comms between the proxy and the sharepoint instance.